# UDEV rules, "NAME" variable not working

Tags: usb, system, udev, devices

I've written a simple udev rule to help me understand the concept

```
#SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{size}=="3913727", SYMLINK="AlphaUSB"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{size}=="3913727", NAME="HelloUSB"
```

The symlink part of the UDEV rule works (it's been commented out) but the Name part of the UDEV rule doesn't work. I'm not sure what i've done wrong?

My second part of the question is, what is the symlink supposed to do when i have created it? I understand that it points to the device file but that's kind of useless. I would like it to point to the mount point so i can use that as a shortcut to get into the USB, any ideas on how i can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't rename a device node by assigning to the `NAME` key in udev rules. At least not in systemd udev. Only a network device name can be changed. From the udev manual:

> ```
>    NAME
>        The name to use for a network interface. See
>        systemd.link(5) for a higher-level mechanism
>        for setting the interface name. The name of a
>        device node cannot be changed by udev, only
>        additional symlinks can be created.
> ```

Any udev symlink for a device is not special in it self. It is just a file system symbolic link to the device node. However, an example of useful usage of udev symlink rules is that because device names depends on the order in which the kernel discover devices, the device name that a specific file system resides on is unpredictable. At one time a thumb drive may get the device name `/dev/sdf`, and at another `/dev/sdg`. Udev rules are usually installed which adds predictable symlink names, like it is done on my Ubuntu laptop in 
`/dev/disk/by-uuid/` where the uuid of the file systems on the disk are symbolic links pointing to the kernel device name.

As for your last question, you can not have a udev symlink point to anything but a device node, so you can not have it point to a mount point:

> ```
>    SYMLINK
>        The name of a symlink targeting the node. Every
>        matching rule adds this value to the list of
>        symlinks to be created.
> ```

To achieve what you want to do, you may give the file system a label, and have the program you use to mount your file systems (udisks2?) use the label in the name of the mount point.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve the problem of not knowing the names of USB devices when multiple USB devices are plugged in the same computer?
The easiest way is using the device names from /dev folder. After plugging the USB adapters, it will automatically generate a serial name for it which you can find it under the /dev/serial/by-id shown as below

```
  /dev/serial/by-id/usb-US_Digital_USB__-__QSB_81658-if00-port0
```

QSB_81658 will eventually a unique name for that USB device.

I tried to write dev rules which was redundant, because every device had its own constant name as shown above. I also came across some issues such as when i was applying dev rules.

Writing dev rules to assign names for individuals. As we know, every QSB-adapter has its own serial number, which you can find on the front part of the black adapter. For my case, I have two QSB0-adapters. One has the serial number of 81830, another one has the serial number of 81658. I will use this attribute (ATTRS{serial}) to assign names to this two adapters.

First, run udevadm to have a look at usb devices details

$ udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0

```
  Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
  walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
  found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
  A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
  and the attributes from one single parent device.

    looking at device '':
      KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
      SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
      DRIVER==""

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/ttyUSB0':
      KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
      DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
      ATTRS{latency_timer}=="16"
      ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0':
      KERNELS=="1-8:1.0"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
      DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
      ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
      ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
      ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
      ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
      ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
      ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
      ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
      ATTRS{interface}=="USB <-> QSB"
      ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8':
      KERNELS=="1-8"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
      DRIVERS=="usb"
      ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
      ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
      ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
      ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
      ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
      ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
      ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
      ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
      ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
      ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
      ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0600"
      ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
      ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
      ATTRS{configuration}==""
      ATTRS{devnum}=="5"
      ATTRS{devpath}=="8"
      ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001"
      ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
      ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
      ATTRS{manufacturer}=="US Digital"
      ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
      ATTRS{product}=="USB <-> QSB"
      ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
      ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
      ATTRS{serial}=="81830"
      ATTRS{speed}=="12"
      ATTRS{urbnum}=="72190"
      ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
      KERNELS=="usb1"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
      DRIVERS=="usb"
      ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
      ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
      ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
      ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
      ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
      ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
      ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
      ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
      ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
      ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
      ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
      ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0404"
      ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
      ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
      ATTRS{configuration}==""
      ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
      ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
      ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
      ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
      ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
      ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
      ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.4.0-128-generic xhci-hcd"
      ATTRS{maxchild}=="16"
      ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
      ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
      ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
      ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
      ATTRS{speed}=="480"
      ATTRS{urbnum}=="129"
      ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
      KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
      SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
      DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
      ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
      ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
      ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
      ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
      ATTRS{device}=="0xa12f"
      ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
      ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
      ATTRS{enable}=="1"
      ATTRS{irq}=="120"
      ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
      ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
      ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
      ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
      ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x8694"
      ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
      ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

    looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
      KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
      SUBSYSTEMS==""
      DRIVERS==""
```

Then you will see one line below from the printed results.

```
            ATTRS{serial}=="81830"
```

Go to directory of /etc/udev/rules.d/

Add 990-usdigital-qsbadapter.rules by using command

```
  sudo nano 990-usdigital-qsbadapter.rules
```

Then put the followings into the file

```
  #This rule file is used to assign names for qsb adapter from USdigital 
  KERNELS=="1-8",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{serial}=="81830",NAME="qsb81830"
  KERNELS=="1-8",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{serial}=="81658",NAME="qsb81658"
```

test your rules, you can run

```
  udevadm control --reload-rules
  udevadm test /dev/serial/by-id/usb-US_Digital_USB__-__QSB_81658-if00-port0
```

Due to permission issues, I could not change NAME.Instead i use SYMLINK.

([UDEV rules, "NAME" variable not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920098/udev-rules-name-variable-not-working)) You can't rename a device node by assigning to the NAME key in udev rules. At least not in systemd udev. Only a network device name can be changed. From the udev manual:

```
  NAME
         The name to use for a network interface. See
         systemd.link(5) for a higher-level mechanism
         for setting the interface name. The name of a
         device node cannot be changed by udev, only
         additional symlinks can be created.
```

So change the rules file contents into #This rule file is used to assign names for qsb adapter from USdigital

```
  ATTRS{serial}=="81830",SYMLINK+="QSB830"
  ATTRS{serial}=="81658",SYMLINK+="QSB658"
```

Please click the picture below to see the result.
[Print results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDWHN.png)